# How do I extend my desktop with an Nvidia 8800 GT graphics card?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, desktop, nvidia-graphics-card

My computer has as Nvidia 8800 GT graphics card with the latest drivers.

I would like to arrange my screens like the below:

1920x1200 on my big Samsung monitor, with the task bar starting and ending in this monitor.
1600x2050 on my small Dell monitor, with **no** task bar - just a blank wallpaper.

I could do this on my laptop. (I'd just plug any monitor in, and the monitor would have a task bar, while the laptop would not have a taskbar - just have a desktop.)

In my Nvidia control center application, I only see "Single, Clone, Horizontal Span, and Vertical Span," but no "Dual View"

How can I achieve the setup I want, with Nvidia Control Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.

Nvidia actually has "Dualview"

you just have to restart your computer, and make sure the monitors are plugged in BEFORE it starts.

Answer (score 1):

Must you do it with the Nvidia panel?

In XP, you can right click your desktop, click "Properties", then the "Settings" tab.

Click the image of your extra monitor, and check the "extend my desktop on to this monitor" checkbox.

It'll be similar on Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal span should do it.